# Forcing Namespace Scope for Standard Namespace

Tags: c++, windows

I had a quick question. Is there a way to force the standard namespace to have the `std::` scope qualifier? Something like `abs` and what not; all `std` functions have to have their scope defined.

I'm not `using namespace std` anywhere nor am I `using std::abs` or something like that. It might be important to say I have `Windows.h` included, which I feel may be where some of these unscoped functions are originating from.

Comment: What version of C++ are you using? It's possible that the operating system and/or compiler have their own versions of these functions (like `abs` etc) which is why `std` is not required, but [`std::abs`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs) does exist so you can still qualify it

Comment: I'm using C++ 17 and compiling with Visual Studio 2019 (which is the same compiler as 2017, I believe, but it has C++ 20 support)

Answer (score 2):

The standard does not forbid other namespaces to have functions that are named `abs` just because there are functions named `abs` in `std` namespace. That's true of all other functions defined in the `std` namespace.

If you want to be certain that you use `std::abs`. and not any other version of `abs`, then by all means, use `std::abs`. Then, it's immaterial whether there are other versions of `abs` defined in the `windows.h` header file.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `abs` instead of `std::abs` you are simply using [abs from C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/abs)

Answer (score 0):

The rule in C++ is that `#include <cmath>` puts the declaration of `abs` in the namespace `std` and is **allowed** to also put the declaration of `abs` in the global namespace.

Another rule in C++ is that `#include <math.h>` puts the declaration of `abs` int he global namespace and is **allowed** to also put the declaration of `abs` in the namespace `std`.

So, no, you can't assume that `#include <cmath>` won't put `abs` into the global namespace.

The reason for this rule instead of the "obvious" one that `#include <cmath>` puts names only in `std` is that the latter rule can be nasty to implement if the C++ implementors don't also have control over the C headers. In that case, the C++ headers would have to have duplicate declarations for all of the C functions, and any change to the C headers would have to be carried through into the C++ headers, which produces a logistical nightmare.